# Restrict possible values in hydra structured configs

Tags: python, fb-hydra

I try to adopt my app for [hydra](https://hydra.cc/) framework. I use [structured config schema](https://hydra.cc/docs/tutorials/structured_config/schema) and I want to restrict possible values for some fields. Is there any way to do that?

Here is my code:

*my_app.py:*

```py
import hydra


@dataclass
class Config:
    # possible values are 'foo' and 'bar'
    some_value: str = "foo"


@hydra.main(config_path="configs", config_name="config")
def main(cfg: Config):
    print(cfg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

*configs/config.yaml:*

```
# value is incorrect.
# I need hydra to throw an exception in this case
some_value: "barrr"
```

Comment: can you use the [Literal](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0586/) type? `some_value: Literal['foo', 'bar']`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A few options:

### 1) If your acceptable values are enumerable, use an `Enum` type:

```py
from enum import Enum
from dataclasses import dataclass

class SomeValue(Enum):
    foo = 1
    bar = 2

@dataclass
class Config:
    # possible values are 'foo' and 'bar'
    some_value: SomeValue = SomeValue.foo
```

If no fancy logic is needed to validate `some_value`, this is the solution I would recommend.

### 2) If you are using yaml files, you can use OmegaConf to register a [custom resolver](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/custom_resolvers.html):

```py
# my_python_file.py
from omegaconf import OmegaConf

def check_some_value(value: str) -> str:
    assert value in ("foo", "bar")
    return value

OmegaConf.register_new_resolver("check_foo_bar", check_some_value)

@hydra.main(...)
...

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

```yaml
# my_yaml_file.yaml
some_value: ${check_foo_bar:foo}
```

When you access `cfg.some_value` in your python code, an `AssertionError` will be raised if the value does not agree with the `check_some_value` function.

### 3) After config composition is completed, you can call [`OmegaConf.to_object`](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#omegaconf-to-object) to create an instance of your dataclass. This means that the dataclass's `__post_init__` function will get called.

```py
import hydra
from dataclasses import dataclass
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf

@dataclass
class Config:
    # possible values are 'foo' and 'bar'
    some_value: str = "foo"

    def __post_init__(self) -> None:
        assert self.some_value in ("foo", "bar")

@hydra.main(config_path="configs", config_name="config")
def main(dict_cfg: DictConfg):
    cfg: Config = OmegaConf.to_object(dict_cfg)
    print(cfg)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: Related: an open feature request to support `typing.Literal`: https://github.com/omry/omegaconf/issues/422